# XNA 4.0 ContentManager Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

What exactly does this do?

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

And how does it relate to:

```
player.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("player"), playerPosition);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

"Content" is the folder/directory where image and model assets are physically stored. There should be a directory in your solution automatically created with a new XNA solution.

```
player.Initialize(Content.Load("player"), playerPosition);
```

Here, a player (custom class I assume) is being initialized with an asset name ("player") to display, and it's position in 2D/3D space.

In essence, the first code is telling the compiler where all the content lives, whereas the second piece of code is loading the asset for the player class.

Comment: May I ask why in:                                        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";                                    that it has to be "Content" or "content" and I cant build it if I set the RootDirectory equal to say:                        "hamburger". Thanks for the explaination of the process though, very helpful.

Comment: You can set your Content.RootDirectory to "hamburger" if you like, however it won't be much good unless that is where your assets are stored. If your assets folder is called "hamburger" this will load content correctly. I'm guessing the project you have started with has a folder called 'Content' where there is a 'player.bmp' or other image. Have a look for a file structure that looks like that, try renaming the 'Content' folder and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your `Content` object is actually a `ContentManager` that is used to load assets.

The first line sets the default directory from where your assets in your Content Project are being loaded.

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

This can avoid always having to specify the full path including folders if your content is else where in your projects structure.

A good place to start to understand how to use these might be reading some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203887). The ContentManager making [Loading Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203875) quite simple. A good idea to make it easier to read your code is to specify the type of the content you are loading as well eg,

```
player.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("player"), playerPosition);
```

This makes it easier to understand what is actually being loaded as file extensions are ommited when loading assets.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

It sets the root directory for `ContentMaganer`. In your XNA solution you usually have 2 projects. One is the project where all your logic is and second is the content project where you put all textures, fonts, sounds etc. If you set that Content manager will look there to load the assets.

```
player.Initialize(Content.Load("player"), playerPosition);
```

Here `ContentManager` of the game is loading player for player initialization. If you set the RootDirectory then `ContentManager` will load `Content.Load("Content/player")`